# Could two women have a child through artificial insemination/genetic engineering?

Tags: genetics, reproduction

This is something I just thought of while looking up stuff about matriarchies.

I recall a comic series I heard of once, I think it was called 'Y, the last man'. In that story, all males (besides the main character, and one monkey he keeps as a pet) were wiped out by a plague or something, leaving the world's population entirely female. They of course start focusing on developing cloning technology to avoid the extinction of the human race.

But thinking about it, would it really be necessary for them to develope such a technology? Afterall, females can already incubate offspring, they just can't impregnate each other. But could it possible to extract the DNA from a woman's egg, and put it in another egg?

Note that I know nothing about artificial insemination or genetic engineering, so I don't know if that would work (I've only heard of people putting one animal's entire genome into an egg, not from two individuals). So I'd like a more expert opinion. Could you actually do that? Or the mechanism for mixing the DNA of two individuals more complicated than that?

Comment: A related [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56229/can-a-human-be-made-with-ovum-but-without-sperm)

Comment: I can't make much sense of the post. But from what I can discern, the answer appears to be 'no'.

Comment: Related https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/27736/3340

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a human be made with ovum but without sperm?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56229/can-a-human-be-made-with-ovum-but-without-sperm)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, researchers have been able to produce sperm and ova from germ cells.  It's not been proven yet that the two can produce a viable embryo, but probably the technique will be perfected eventually. [https://www.technologyreview.com/s/608452/a-new-way-to-reproduce/]

Answer (score 1):

Dolly the sheep was made by somatic cell nuclear transfer.  Scientists in China claim to have cloned a monkey in the same way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_cell_nuclear_transfer